# Optimizing windowed feature generation from input image in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, window, feature-extraction

I have created a script in Python which takes an image as input and produces a new image where each pixel corresponds to a feature calculated from the windowed group of pixels in the input image. The following picture will highlight this idea:

[image]

In the border cases we can either insert `NaN` into the output image or just use the pixels we have available inside the window. What would be an optimized way to do achieve this functionality in Python or some other programming language? At the moment, my script is simply using a bunch of `for`-loops to get the job done.  Here you can see the code:

```
# This function will return the statistical features
# 
#
# INPUTS: 
# 'data' the data from which statistical features are to be calculated
# "winSize" specifying the window size, must be odd and > 1
#
# OUTPUT: 
# 'meanData, stdData' statistical feature matrices (numpy ndarrays)

def get_stat_feats(data, winSize):

    rows = data.shape[0]
    cols = data.shape[1]
    dist = int(math.floor(float(winSize)/2.0))
    neigh = range(-dist, dist+1)
    temp = np.zeros((int(winSize)**2, 1))
    meanData = np.zeros(data.shape)
    stdData = np.zeros(data.shape)
    for row in range(0, rows):
        for col in range(0, cols):
            index = 0
            makeNaN = 0
            for y in neigh:
                for x in neigh: 
                    indY = row + y
                    indX = col + x
                    # Check that we are inside the image
                    if indY >= 0 and indY <= rows-1 and indX >= 0 and indX <= cols-1:
                        temp[index] = data[indY, indX]
                        index += 1
                    else: 
                        makeNaN = 1
            if makeNaN == 1:
                meanData[row, col] = np.NAN
                stdData[row, col] = np.NAN

            else:
                meanData[row, col] = np.mean(temp)
                stdData[row, col] = np.std(temp)       
    return meanData, stdData
```

Thnx for any help! =) If there any more information needed, please ask =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[generic_filter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.generic_filter.html) from scipy.ndimage should be a decent solution for this. Probably faster solution, but this is the simplest i think.

It can take a mode parameter to define how to handle the edges. For example you could set it to treat elements outside the border to constant and equal NaN like this:

`generic_filter(a, f, size=winSize, mode='constant', cval=np.nan)`

```
def get_stat_feats(data, winSize):
    from scipy.ndimage import generic_filter
    import numpy as np
    mean = lambda x: x.mean()
    std = lambda x: x.std()

    meanData = generic_filter(data, mean, size=winSize)
    stdData = generic_filter(data, std, size=winSize)

    return meanData, stdData
```

force float and round return value:

```
import numpy as np

def get_stat_feats(data, winSize):
    from scipy.ndimage import generic_filter
    import numpy as np
    data = data.astype(float)
    mean = lambda x: x.mean()
    std = lambda x: x.std()

    meanData = generic_filter(data, mean, size=winSize)
    stdData = generic_filter(data, std, size=winSize)

    return np.round(meanData,2), np.round(stdData, 2)
```

Comment: hi again @M4rtini ! Your solution works great, but I have one small problem. The values the generic_filter returns are integers...my own method returns float values. How could I preserve the precision with the generic_filter? For example my function returns a value (for one pixel) 5.35412613 and the generic_filter returns 5? The best would be to perhaps round the value to 3 digits e.g. 5.35

Comment: It should return the same type as the input data is. But if you want to force float. you could do `data = data.astype(float)` at the start of `get_stat_feats`

Comment: @jjepsuomi added a version forcing float and rounding the return value to 2 decimal values.

Comment: +1 @M4rtini Thank you for your help! That did it! It did not return at first float, because my data had values from 0-255 integer typed values =) But when I converted it into float as you suggested, et voila! ;D thnx